# game-rec tag - four questions that need action

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Something needs doing with [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) - this tag is already marked clearly as off topic but has four questions against it that need some action taking against them. All four questions are only using the [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) tag so removing this tag will result in four off topic questions against [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion in this case is to have someone collect the useful bits and perhaps make a blog post, then remove the questions/answers.  There's probably useful "general information" in there somewhere that we can repurpose, even if the Q&A portion of the site is an inappropriate place.

Comment: I've been meaning to do this for a while now, and just now got to it today.  Once I've extracted any useful info for the post, I'll delete the remaining questions.

Comment: REJOICE!  The blog post is scheduled for tomorrow.  I shall verily deletify the questions now.

Answer (score 4):

All three of which were our failed experiments to resolve the debacle in which we decree game-recs off topic by trying to create canonical Community Wiki's. We should probably just delete them all at this point.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be the Historical Lock, if it's deemed appropriate in this case:

[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: I would definitely be in favour of using a historical lock, especially for [this guy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11164/1351).  IMHO, we should be using it more often for old questions instead of just closing them.

Comment: @MBraedley, it doesn't seem a popular choice amongst the community.  I'm hoping to capture any useful tidbits in this blog post, however, so the end result might be quite similar.

Answer (score -5):

Why not let them happen? and add some sort of filter for people that do not want to see them?

heck, i'd love to browse stackoverflow without the java tag. let's kill that one while we're at it.

Comment: The difference here is that game recommendation is [off topic in our FAQ.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)  These questions are a relic from a time when they were on topic, however.  I imagine SO would have to take some similar action if Java was ever determined to be off-topic, although that seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: so because it's in the FAQ it's the truth? if that was so you wouldn't have to delete so many questions like that. Anyway, that's my view. if something is to be created and rated in the community, just let it be done that way. I had lots of fun in an old game identification question i asked here. even learned that the game studio has new titles. i will still find that question and answers useful no matter what you write in the FAQ :) ... but i think that i understand the idea now that i read the FAQ... maybe this site should be renamed to gameguide.stackexchange to be clearer. not trolling.