# What can we do about the three general game recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [game-rec tag - four questions that need action](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5205/game-rec-tag-four-questions-that-need-action)

The tag [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) was scheduled for death via the [Great Arqade Clean-Up of 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012). There are currently five questions in it. Two of the questions mistakenly had the tag added after the fact and could just be deleted outright:

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91755/gamepad-friendly-pc-strategy-games
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/recommend-a-multiplayer-game-for-kids

However, we have three general questions about game advice that remain open:

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/if-i-like-game-x-how-do-i-find-similar-games
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11551/how-to-find-out-about-overlooked-underrated-games
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/gaming-resources-how-can-i-find-new-games-to-play

Is there some way we can retag them so that [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) can finally die an ignoble death?

Comment: We had this question, and I keep meaning to do the blog thing or the delete thing.  Then I get distracted.  Thanks for reminding me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crazy idea, but honestly, all three of them are pretty bad/vaguely dupes of each other. Why not just nuke them all and put this whole sordid chapter of our history behind us?

Comment: Sure, whatever, I don't care.